# Can I instantiate multiple instances of one program based on different configuration files?

Tags: python

I need to be able to run different instances of the same program structure that each uses different configuration files in JSON. I have several configuration files in JSON, and for each of them I would need to run different instances of the same program. Each instance would need to run separately and based on referenced configuration have some processes. Is this possible with python, and if yes could instantiation be automatic, or could some external request trigger instantiation of that program with specific configuration file?

I also need to be able to distoy it after the job is done. Manually or automatically.

P.S. There should be only one file, that would be called.

Comment: Could you share sample code/JSON data that you use to understand the problem better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) and pass in the config file as a parameter. That would allow multiple executions with different configs.

  ```
  python myscript.py --config config1.json
  python myscript.py --config configTWO.json
  python myscript.py --config "C:\Users\you\Documents\superconfig.json"
  ```
- You can also do it with [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv).
- And since you're passing in the json *file* name, use argparse's [`FileType objects`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#filetype-objects).

Comment: Yes, but last call overwrites the previous always. I need to run them in the background and that all are active in the same time. Lets say myscript.py publishes message every second that I pass as a parameter. If I call it 3 times with different arguments, I should receive 3 different messages every second. Now I receive only last one.

Comment: Then you're _writing_ your results somewhere which overwrites your previous result. That's a different problem, has nothing to do with calling the same program 3 times with diff parameters. Show the code of what you're doing in your script. Are you using threading? Are you writing results to the same text file or something like that?

Comment: MQTT was causing problem with its client name. It works fine without client name. Thanks @aneroid